# Can't open EPS files generated by matplotlib

Tags: linux, matplotlib, ghostscript

I used `plt.savefig(name, format='eps')` in python. I used GIMP, LibreOffice, Okular, Evince, and Ghostscript directly, and none of them are able to open the result. It works when it is saved as a PNG, but not as an EPS. I am using Linux.

This is the error that gs gives:

> GPL Ghostscript 9.54.0 (2021-03-30)
> Copyright (C) 2021 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
> This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
> see the file COPYING for details.
> Error: /undefined in --setcachedevice--
> Operand stack:
> CharStrings   --dict:17/30(L)--   e   --nostringval--   1300   0   113   -29   1114   1556
> Execution stack:
> %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1990   1   3   %oparray_pop   1989   1   3   %oparray_pop   1988   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   1977   1   3   %oparray_pop   1833   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
> Dictionary stack:
> --dict:730/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:80/200(L)--   --dict:10/11(L)--   --dict:6/10(L)--   --dict:17/30(L)--
> Current allocation mode is local
> Current file position is 9738
> GPL Ghostscript 9.54.0: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Evince gives this:

> (libspectre) ghostscript reports: undefined -21
> (libspectre) ghostscript reports: undefined -21

When I ran the command file, the result seemed to indicate that it is a valid eps file:

> PostScript document text conforming DSC level 3.0, type EPS

As I've done a little more testing with this, the EPS file opens fine when I do not provide a legend. However, when I do add labels and a legend, ghostscript is unable to open the file:

Here is the code:

```py
for graph in graphs:
    # Split the file extension from name
    name = graph.filename.split('.', 1)[0]
    # Get the values for X. This will act as x-axis
    X = graph.data_dict['X']
    # Go through each column (except for X) and plot
    for column in (i for i in graph.data_dict if i != 'X'):
        # Get the data for the column
        y = graph.data_dict[column]
        # Plot it
        plt.plot(X,y,label=column)
        plt.yticks(fontsize="small")
    # Set the title to the file name
    plt.title(name)
    # X is the x label
    plt.xlabel('X')
    plt.xticks(fontsize="small")
    # Provide a legend
    plt.legend()
    plt.margins(0, tight=True)

    plt.savefig(name + ".eps", format='eps')
```

This will correctly show:

```py
for graph in graphs:
    # Split the file extension from name
    name = graph.filename.split('.', 1)[0]
    # Get the values for X. This will act as x-axis
    X = graph.data_dict['X']
    # Go through each column (except for X) and plot
    for column in (i for i in graph.data_dict if i != 'X'):
        # Get the data for the column
        y = graph.data_dict[column]
        # Plot it
        plt.plot(X,y)
        plt.yticks(fontsize="small")
    # Set the title to the file name
    # X is the x label
    plt.xticks(fontsize="small")
    # Provide a legend
    plt.margins(0, tight=True)

    plt.savefig(name + ".eps", format='eps')
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for your question to be answered. Please edit your question to include code which can produce your error.

Comment: Mostly likely we'd need to see the eps file in order to comment sensibly.

Comment: I have added some code that will hopefully give clarification what is producing the error.